# Comparing two classifiers with two proportion ztest by using balanced accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, z-test

I'm looking for statistical differences between two classifiers by applying the two proportion z-test formula to them and then performing the hypothesis test.

If p1 and p2 are the balanced accuracy scores of classifiers 1 and 2.

```
p = (p1+p2)/2
z = (p1-p2) / √p(1-p)(1/n1+1/n2) = (p1-p2) / √p(1-p)(2/n)
```

I was wondering about the **n** at the denominator.
According to balancing of the classes in the test-set, Should the ***n*** be "weighted" in some way ? How ?

Comment: Did the classifiers classify the same objects once, the same ones multiple times, partially overlapping subsets, or completely different objects? If the objects were not the same for the classifiers, how were they assigned to objects (or the other way round), e.g. by randomization? Depending on the answer to that very different approaches would be needed. A simple two proportion test would make sense when the two classifiers classified different objects with assignment by randomization.  By the way, for $p$, did you forget a minus sign? Note also: https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/

Comment: Thanks, very good questions @Björn. The testset has been created by train_test_split function of sklearn by settings the params: shuffle=True, test_size=0.15, stratify=y_labels. The metrics of balanced accuracy scores are collected by applying the two classifiers over the same test set. In the global dataset every object that i want to classify can be repeated more than one. P should be right. Some noise can be added at least I guess.